# Error when installing famo.us

Tags: node.js, npm, famo.us, famous-cli

I have node.js installed, and I want to install fam.us (http://famous.org/get-started.html)

I tried this command

```
npm install -g famous-cli
```

but I get an error, does anyone know how to fix it?

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Apps\Messenger>npm install -g famous-cli
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\famous -> C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\famous-cli\bin\famous.js
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "famous-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "famous-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "famous-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\phonegap-build requires colors@'0.6.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\connect\node_modules\multiparty\nod
e_modules\stream-counter requires readable-stream@'~1.1.8' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\connect\node_modules\multiparty\nod
e_modules\readable-stream,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.13-1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\winston requires colors@'0.x.x' but will load

npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
famous-cli@0.2.6 C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\famous-cli
├── btoa@1.1.2
├── mime@1.3.4
├── minimist@1.1.0
├── async@0.9.0
├── mixpanel@0.2.1
├── isbinaryfile@2.0.3
├── commander@2.7.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
├── combined-stream@1.0.3 (delayed-stream@1.0.0)
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1
.3.1, has-ansi@1.0.3, strip-ansi@2.0.1)
├── mime-types@2.0.12 (mime-db@1.10.0)
├── recursive-readdir@1.2.1 (minimatch@0.3.0)
├── latest-version@1.0.0 (package-json@1.1.0)
├── fs-extra@0.18.4 (jsonfile@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.7, rimraf@2.3.4)
├── tar@2.1.1 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.8, fstream@1.0.6)
├── node-rest-client@1.4.4 (xml2js@0.4.8)
└── inquirer@0.8.2 (figures@1.3.5, ansi-regex@1.1.1, cli-width@1.0.1, through@2.
3.7, readline2@0.1.1, lodash@3.9.2, rx@2.5.2)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "famous-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1

npm ERR! Callback called more than once.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Apps\Messenger\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Apps\Messenger>npm install -g famous-cli
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\famous -> C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\famous-cli\bin\famous.js
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\phonegap-build requires colors@'0.6.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\connect\node_modules\multiparty\nod
e_modules\stream-counter requires readable-stream@'~1.1.8' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\connect\node_modules\multiparty\nod
e_modules\readable-stream,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.13-1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\winston requires colors@'0.x.x' but will load

npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
famous-cli@0.2.6 C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\famous-cli
├── btoa@1.1.2
├── mime@1.3.4
├── async@0.9.0
├── minimist@1.1.0
├── mixpanel@0.2.1
├── combined-stream@1.0.3 (delayed-stream@1.0.0)
├── isbinaryfile@2.0.3
├── commander@2.7.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
├── mime-types@2.0.12 (mime-db@1.10.0)
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1
.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
├── recursive-readdir@1.2.1 (minimatch@0.3.0)
├── latest-version@1.0.0 (package-json@1.1.0)
├── fs-extra@0.18.4 (jsonfile@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.7, rimraf@2.3.4)
├── tar@2.1.1 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.8, fstream@1.0.6)
├── node-rest-client@1.4.4 (xml2js@0.4.8)
└── inquirer@0.8.2 (figures@1.3.5, ansi-regex@1.1.1, cli-width@1.0.1, through@2.
3.7, readline2@0.1.1, lodash@3.9.2, rx@2.5.2)

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Apps\Messenger>npm install -g famous-cli
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\famous -> C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\famous-cli\bin\famous.js
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\phonegap-build requires colors@'0.6.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\connect\node_modules\multiparty\nod
e_modules\stream-counter requires readable-stream@'~1.1.8' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\connect\node_modules\multiparty\nod
e_modules\readable-stream,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.13-1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\winston requires colors@'0.x.x' but will load

npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
famous-cli@0.2.6 C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\famous-cli
├── btoa@1.1.2
├── mime@1.3.4
├── minimist@1.1.0
├── async@0.9.0
├── mixpanel@0.2.1
├── isbinaryfile@2.0.3
├── combined-stream@1.0.3 (delayed-stream@1.0.0)
├── commander@2.7.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1
.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
├── mime-types@2.0.12 (mime-db@1.10.0)
├── recursive-readdir@1.2.1 (minimatch@0.3.0)
├── latest-version@1.0.0 (package-json@1.1.0)
├── fs-extra@0.18.4 (jsonfile@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.7, rimraf@2.3.4)
├── tar@2.1.1 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.8, fstream@1.0.6)
├── node-rest-client@1.4.4 (xml2js@0.4.8)
└── inquirer@0.8.2 (figures@1.3.5, ansi-regex@1.1.1, cli-width@1.0.1, through@2.
3.7, readline2@0.1.1, lodash@3.9.2, rx@2.5.2)

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Apps\Messenger>npm install -g famous-cli
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\famous -> C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\no
de_modules\famous-cli\bin\famous.js
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\phonegap-build requires colors@'0.6.x' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\connect\node_modules\multiparty\nod
e_modules\stream-counter requires readable-stream@'~1.1.8' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\connect\node_modules\multiparty\nod
e_modules\readable-stream,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.13-1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\prompt\node_modules\winston requires colors@'0.x.x' but will load

npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonega
p\node_modules\colors,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.6.0-1
famous-cli@0.2.6 C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\famous-cli
├── btoa@1.1.2
├── mime@1.3.4
├── minimist@1.1.0
├── async@0.9.0
├── mixpanel@0.2.1
├── combined-stream@1.0.3 (delayed-stream@1.0.0)
├── isbinaryfile@2.0.3
├── mime-types@2.0.12 (mime-db@1.10.0)
├── commander@2.7.1 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1
.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
├── recursive-readdir@1.2.1 (minimatch@0.3.0)
├── latest-version@1.0.0 (package-json@1.1.0)
├── fs-extra@0.18.4 (jsonfile@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.7, rimraf@2.3.4)
├── tar@2.1.1 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.8, fstream@1.0.6)
├── node-rest-client@1.4.4 (xml2js@0.4.8)
└── inquirer@0.8.2 (figures@1.3.5, ansi-regex@1.1.1, cli-width@1.0.1, through@2.
3.7, readline2@0.1.1, lodash@3.9.2, rx@2.5.2)

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Apps\Messenger>
```

Comment: It seems to be installed. What is the error that you are getting when you run 'famous'?

Comment: I don't see the famo.us  folder, any other module i install, I can see it in the same directory.

Comment: famous-cli is the command. It won't create the folder. Run 'famous create yourprojectname' to create the famous project folder.

Comment: I updated to latest node version, and then it only gave unmet dependency warnings with phone gap, but no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your main error seems to be `ECONNRESET`, which npm conveniently describes to you in the error log :

*This is most likely not a problem with npm itself and is related to network connectivity. In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.*

You should check you WiFi or network cable and try again. Clearing your npm dependencies and start from scratch may help :

```sh
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf ~/.npm
rm -rf [your node path]/lib/node_modules
```